# Destroying child record destroys parent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, parent-child, destroy

**EDIT: I solved my problem. Instead of a type 'DELETE' AJAX call, I used a type 'POST' call with the {:method: 'DELETE'} as its data value. This seemed to do the trick.**

I'm trying to allow deletion of a child element in Rails 4 via an AJAX request, and I'm having this issue. I have a Badge model which has many BadgeElements. The BadgeElements controller contains a destroy method which I know works because in my Show view, the elements are properly being deleted. It's when I try to delete them in my JavaScript file with AJAX that I'm having trouble. Here's my code:

```
function deleteElement(id) {
  var path_root = $('form').attr('action');
  var delete_path = path_root + "/badge_elements/" + id;
  $.ajax({
    url: delete_path, 
    type: 'DELETE' 
  });
  $('form').load(path_root + "/edit form");
}
```

The delete_path attribute evaluates to /badges/[badge_id]/badge_elements/[id], where [id] is the id of the specific element in question. When this function is executed, I get a 400 error at the path ending in /badges, which tells me the badge itself is being deleted. I can confirm this by reloading the page and getting the error "Could not find Badge with badge_id = 4", etc. For reference, here's the model and destroy method for BadgeElement:

badge_element.rb:

```
class BadgeElement < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :badge
  belongs_to :font
  scope :front, -> {where(side:"front")}
  scope :back, -> {where(side:"back")}
  validates :font_id, presence: true
end
```

in badge_elements_controller.rb:

```
def destroy
  badge = Badge.find(params[:badge_id])
  badge_element = BadgeElement.find(params[:id])
  badge_element.destroy
  redirect_to badge_path(badge)
end
```

Does anyone know what's going on? Thanks.

Comment: Add model `associations` and `destroy` action of `badge_elements` to your ques

Comment: Can you confirm, that path_root is "badge/:id" and nothing more? just console.log(path_root) in your js. i  have a feeling that there is something extra in your path_root like # or ? .

Comment: Also if you can show the tail of your development log to see if it is indeed getting an ajax call to the controller, what the params are, and if there are any errors

Comment: @PavelS yes, I can. I'm certain I'm getting the proper path. On my last attempt I got /badges/7/badge_elements/493

Comment: @emcanes my development log shows a DELETE request for badges/7, processed from the Badges controller. This is clearly the issue, but I don't know why it's happening since my path should be correct.

Comment: What about your routes.rb, do you have it declared as nested resources?

Answer (score 1):

I've just had this problem.

If your controller has a `redirect_to` and no sensitivity to the format of the request it will redirect to `badge_path(badge)` as instructed but the method will still be **DELETE**, thereby deleting the parent as well as the child.

I think you'll just need a `respond_to` block like so

```
def destroy
  ...
  respond_to do |format| 
    format.html { redirect_to badge_path(badge) }
    format.js { }
  end
end
```